# intermittent blank/partial screenshots of WKWebView using takeSnapshot

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, screenshot, wkwebview

I am taking a screenshot of a WKVebView in the completion handler of a javascript evaluation:

```
func loadPage(){
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "...")
    let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "...")
    webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: baseUrl)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("....") { (result, error) in
        let configuration = WKSnapshotConfiguration()
        configuration.rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: (self.webView?.frame.size)!)
        self.webView!.takeSnapshot(with: configuration, completionHandler: { (image, error) in
            // do something with the image
        })
}
```

Even if it is in the completion handler of the `webView.evaluateJavaScript` function, the content if often not finished to render and I am getting either blank screenshot or partial ones (only some elements are present).

How can I ensure that rendering is completed before taking screenshot (I do not want to introduce fixed delay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As content of WebView is bigger than the screen size so first we will get height and width of the content after that we will take a screenshot

```
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    // Will get Height and Width of the Content

    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                guard let contentHeight = height as? CGFloat else { print("Content height could not be obtained"); return }
                self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollWidth", completionHandler: { [weak self](width, error) in
                    let contentWidth = width as! CGFloat
                    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
                    self?.takeScreenshot(rect)
                })
            })
        }
    })

}
```

Once we will get the Height and Width, we will call below method to capture Screenshot

```
func takeScreenshot(_ rect: CGRect) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(".....") { (result, error) in
        let configuration = WKSnapshotConfiguration()
        configuration.rect = rect//CGRect(origin: .zero, size: (self.webView?.frame.size)!)
        self.webView!.takeSnapshot(with: configuration, completionHandler: { (image, error) in
            // do something with the image
            print("image:\(image!)")
        })
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: When you evaluateJavascript, this delegate is unfortunately not called.

Comment: ok got it, can you show me code where you are loading html in WKWebView

Comment: @AP. I have edited my answer, please try it will work.

Comment: @AP. Please check and let me know.

Comment: @AP. unfortunately there is no way to wait, we can put only timer. above solution is not working ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait till all the elements are loaded in the webview.
You can add timer before taking screenshot.

RunLoop.main.run(until: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.5))